# Objective C : How to store the sqlite3 database outside the application folder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, ipa

I am working on an app and I am storing my data locally using SQLite 3. Now I will have updated versions of the same app in future and I will have to update the same using downloading and installing the new IPA file after removing it only.

But here the problem occurs. The client wants that the data stored locally in the prior version should be replaced in the newer version without using the web server.

I surfed [several](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6239-database-sync-between-iphone-server.html) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086873/how-to-store-iphone-apps-data-even-if-it-is-uninstalled) and all results into negative response still I would like to know if there is any way with the help of which I can store my database outside application folder in such a way that even the removal of app does not affect the database and the newer version can fetch the data from the same database. Or any other way around? Thanks for response in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the database in the `Documents` folder as all the content inside it remains there even if an app is updated via the app store (If you remove the app then this also gets deleted.. so keep this in mind )

you can create a separate folder inside the `Documents` folder named `Database` and store your file inside in.. you can create a path like this..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database"];
```

**EDIT:**

Since you want to keep it even after the deletion of app, I don't think you can do it on the device due to the sandboxing feature of the apps but you still you have one more option..

You can backup this database on your personal server and every time the app is installed it should query the server if a database for that particular user exists or not. If it exists than you can download and store it in documents directory else you give him a new database. You can perform this backup every once in a while or provide a sync option for the user himself. hoping this helps.

Comment: Thanks ankit,I am already doing that.but I want to store my database in such a way that even the deletion of the app keeps a copy of the database.Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

iCloud includes Backup, which automatically backs up a user’s iOS device daily over Wi-Fi. Everything in your app’s home directory is backed up, with the exception of the application bundle itself, the caches directory and temp directory. Purchased music, apps, books, the Camera Roll, device settings, home screen and app organization, messages and ringtones are backed up as well. Because backups are done wirelessly and stored in iCloud for each user, it’s best to minimize the amount of data that’s stored for your app. Large files will lengthen the time it takes to perform a backup and consume more of a user’s available iCloud storage.

To ensure that backups are as efficient as possible, be sure to store your app’s data according to the following guidelines:

1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.
2. Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the /Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you should put in the Caches directory include database cache files and downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map applications.
3. Data that is used only temporarily should be stored in the /tmp directory. Although these files are not backed up to iCloud, remember to delete those files when you are done with them so that they do not continue to consume space on the user’s device.
4. Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in, including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible for monitoring and purging these files periodically. Learn more

For more information read the iOS App Programming Guide.

Comment: I really do not think you can post this here… At the very least to view this content on Apple's website I had to log in as iOS Developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep app data when removing the app, you basically have two options:

- Store the app data on a your server
- Sync the app data to a cloud service such as [iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html)

There is no way (AFAIK) to keep app data on the device after removing the app.

Comment: is the second way guaranteed to work..? Coz I was wondering if the app is deleted and a sync is performed after that with the iCloud than all its contents will also be deleted...?

Comment: The iCloud API uses a special daemon to sync with the service. I believe that it will still sync the changes even if you delete the app, but you obviously have to test this carefully if it is important for the function of your app.

Comment: I can confirm that iCloud solution will work.  As long as you do not delete the local copy of the file (your db file) before deleting your app, then your db file will still be in your iCloud container.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store any user data outside of Documents folder because Apple is against it. If you do store user data in some other place - you will get your app rejected during Apple app review.

Comment: can you provide me some link or sort of thing stating the same. That will help me a lot.